# is this right way to send state data from parent to child

Tags: dart, flutter

**Are there any other better ways to send data**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './bottomNav.dart';

void main()=>runApp(Parent());

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {  
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _ParentState();
  }
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent>{
  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return (
      MaterialApp(
        home:Material(
          child:Center(
            child:Child1(cont:count)
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class Child1 extends StatelessWidget {
  int cont;
  Child1({this.cont});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    print('context ${cont}');
    return Text('This is child ${cont}',);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or if it's straight forward you can set your data when you init your `statefulWidget` and use it in a child using `widget.count`

Comment: can you explain with some code please

Answer (score 1):

You can use `InheritedModel` for pass data between classes.
[watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ml5uefGgkaA)